# Draw image from transformed imageview

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-graphics, cgcontext

I want to draw image from transformed `uiimageview` - refer left side image,

Dragview  = UIImageView that can be rotated or scaled using some controls, and I need to draw that transformed image at same position

I am facing problem with Transformation (`CGContextConcatCTM`),

It gives required output if

```
CGAffineTransform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
```

but I got wrong origin on output image with same transformation

below is my code to draw image same like original imageview

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(1024, 768));
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextConcatCTM(context, dragView.originalTransform);  
UIImage *curImage1 = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

[image: Refer below image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, 0.0);
[view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: No, I have tried this, this will draw at point (0,0) with no transformation

Comment: You should explain what this code does so that the OP (and other users) can understand what is happening.

Comment: UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions  
Creates a bitmap-based graphics context with the specified options.

View is the view you want to capture as an image... First parameter is the size, second is the opaque and third is the scale!  The scale factor to apply to the bitmap. If you specify a value of 0.0, the scale factor is set to the scale factor of the device’s main screen.  

then view.layer renderinContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() will basically return the graphic context of the view.... and finally we save everything in an image.